# Resetting the session in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

When I change a setting in my PowerShell profile, I am closing the PowerShell window and reopening it to reset the session.

I assume there is a better command or cmdlet to refresh the session. Any clue?

Comment: there are many cmdlets/fuction (google search) doing close and reopen session but I don't know any tricks that reset the console state like closing and re-open from start.

Comment: exit works for shuting down the console completely but not what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just dotsource your profile.

```
. $Profile
```

If your profile handles errors when things like drives, or vars even exists, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and dot-source your profile instead though some things may not work (like trying to redefine constants, etc).

A blog post to restart the shell:

http://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2006/12/restart-your-engins-powershell-way_28.html